# ¿Por qué mis funciones con el decorador bot.command() no funcionan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

He creado un bot en Python para Discord, que tiene dos funciones:

1. Busca palabras clave en los mensajes que se mandan.
2. Ejecuta comandos cuando una función es llamada en el canal de texto (e.j: `.add 10 10`).

El problema es que solo se ejecuta la función de buscar palabras clave. La otra no funciona.

Código:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import datetime

#Inicializacion de comandos
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".", description = "Bot that evaluates Python expresions")
client = discord.Client()

#Mi ID
MYID = xxxxx
TOKEN = "xxxxx"

#Funciones
def n_upper_chars(string):
    return sum(map(str.isupper, string))


#Códigos para funciones
#Funciones para sumar, restar, dividir y multiplicar
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, num1 = None, num2 = None):
    try:
        await ctx.send("The answer to " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " is " + str(int(num1) + int(num2)) + " :smiley:")
    except:
        await ctx.send("Error while adding :cry:")

@bot.command()
async def sub(ctx, num1 = None, num2 = None):
    try:
        await ctx.send("The answer to " + num1 + " - " + num2 + " is " + str(int(num1) - int(num2)) + " :smiley:")
    except:
        await ctx.send("Error while substracting :cry:")
    
@bot.command()
async def mul(ctx, num1 = None, num2 = None):
    try:
        await ctx.send("The answer to " + num1 + " x " + num2 + " is " + str(int(num1) * int(num2)) + " :smiley:")
    except:
        await ctx.send("Error while multiplying :cry:")

@bot.command()
async def div(ctx, num1 = None, num2 = None):
    try:
        await ctx.send("The answer to " + num1 + " ÷ " + num2 + " is " + str(int(num1) / int(num2)) + " :smiley:")
    except:
        await ctx.send("Error while dividing :cry:")

            
    #Acciones personalizadas
    #Malas
    if "https://discord." in message.content.lower():
        if (userID == bot.user.id) or (userID == MYID):
            pass
        else:
            await message.channel.send("<@" + str(userID) + "> don't put external servers' links! :rage:")
            await message.delete()
    elif n_upper_chars(message.content) >= 8:
        if (userID == bot.user.id) or (userID == MYID):
            pass
        else:
            await message.channel.send("<@" + str(userID) + "> too many caps! :rage:")
            await message.delete()


#Empezar el programa    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot listo")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Creo que tiene algo que ver con los decoradores. La función que funciona esta dentro del decorador `bot.event`. En cambio, las que no funcionan, están dentro de `bot.command()`.

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, he encontrado mi propia respuesta:

En vez de colocar el decorador `bot.event` en la función de palabras clave, coloqué `bot.listen()` y ahora funciona correctamente.

Saludos :)